# Using SpecFlowPlus@0 in YAML pipeline, the project name is getting ommitted from the path to the testAssembly

Tags: automated-tests, azure-pipelines, specflow, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am getting this error even when I hard code the entire path from the volume to the file.

> Error: Cannot find the specified testAssembly: D:\Agent_work\2\s\bin\Debug\net6.0\company_com.dll
> ##[error]Error: Command failed: dotnet "D:\Agent_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll" test-assembly "bin\Debug\net6.0\company_com.dll" --output-type JSON --test-execution-json "bin\Debug\net6.0\TestExecution.json" --binding-assemblies "bin\Debug\net6.0\company_com.dll" --include-test-output "All" --output "D:\Agent_work\2\s\76364\FeatureData.json" --project-name "Web site testing" --project-language "en"

The YAML code looks like this:

```
stages:
- stage: 'Prerequisites'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Env_Setup'
    pool:
      name: 'Web App Testing'
    steps:
    - task: ScreenResolutionUtility@1
      inputs:
        displaySettings: 'specific'
        width: '1920'
        height: '1080'
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.x'
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x
        vsVersion: 17.0.0
        includePreviewVersions: true
      #enabled: false
 
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: 'Install SpecFlow+LivingDoc'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script:  #dotnet tool update --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI
      continueOnError: true
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.8.x'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.9.1
        # checkLatest: true
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
      displayName:
      inputs:
        #nuGetServiceConnections: # string. Service connection credentials for feeds outside this organization. 
        forceReinstallCredentialProvider: false # boolean. Reinstall the credential provider even if already installed. Default: false.
        
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build the projects'
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: '**\*.csproj'
      --------
      All the builds and runs are fine. We pickup on the SpecFlow task
      --------

   - task: SpecFlowPlus@0
     displayName: 'Generate the SpecFlow + LivingDocs reports for C.com'
     inputs:
       generatorSource: 'FeatureFolder'
       projectFilePath: 'D:\Agent\_work\2\s\C.com'
       testAssemblyFilePath: 'D:\Agent\_work\2\s\C.com\bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll'
       projectName: 'Company.com site'
       testExecutionJson: 'D:\Agent\_work\2\s\C.com\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestExecution.json'
       projectLanguage: 'en'
       bindingAssemblies: 'D:\Agent\_work\2\s\C.com\bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll'
       output: 'FeatureData.json'
     continueOnError: true
```

And here is the error with the stack trace info

```
Error: Cannot find the specified testAssembly: D:\Agent\_work\2\s\bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll
   at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
   at Object.execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
   at D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:138:46
   at step (D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:44:23)
   at Object.next (D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:25:53)
   at D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:19:71
   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
   at __awaiter (D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:15:12)
   at D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:77:12
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\index.js:172:3)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Command failed: dotnet "D:\Agent\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll" test-assembly "bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll" --output-type JSON --test-execution-json "**\TestExecution.json" --binding-assemblies "bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll" --include-test-output "All" --output "D:\Agent\_work\2\s\76140\FeatureData.json" --project-name "Web site testing" --project-language "en"
Error: Cannot find the specified testAssembly: D:\Agent\_work\2\s\bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll

   at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
```

I've tried numerous ways of formulating the path to get around this and in every case it is omiting the project directory name in the path. This is a self hosted agent so I have access to the server in question and can see the path in question. The only odd thing That I am doing that might account for this, though I couldn't say why, is forcing the use of dotNet Core 6.0.

To do that I edited the LivingDoc.CLI.runtimeconfig.json as I wanted to run everything on the same .NET Core major version

```
{
 "runtimeOptions": {
   "tfm": "net6.0",
   "rollForward": "Major",
   "framework": {
     "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
     "version": "6.0.1"
   }
 }
}
```

I copied the erroring commnd into a cmd on the server and it runs successfully:

> D:\somepath>dotnet "D:\Agent_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.964\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll" test-assembly "bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll" --output-type JSON --test-execution-json "**\TestExecution.json" --binding-assemblies "bin\Debug\net6.0\Company_com.dll" --include-test-output "All" --output "D:\Agent_work\2\s\76163\FeatureData.json" --project-name "Web site testing" --project-language "en"

I have attempted to specify the projectPath as relative to the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) as well to no effect. Nothing I change in the path has any effect. I am left wondering if this is something internal to the project or a json file setting that I'm missing